# Define State Body in TikZ-UML

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I want to define a custom statechart using TikZ-UML (http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php). My problem is that the state does not seem to render the content in its body.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlstate}[name=State]{A State}
Some

State

Content

$$x = y$$
\end{umlstate}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know whether this is a TikZ or TikZ-UML specific issue? And ideally: How would one display abitrary content here?

Comment: According to TikZ-UML documentation about [`states`](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en&id=doc#t-3) it looks like it's not possible to include *regular* text inside `states`. All examples show how to include other `uml` commands, but no one shows text.

Comment: Regarding the usage of `$$` for math, pleas take a look at [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It may be still not documented (if it is the case, this will be fixed soon), but you can use `\umlstatetext`to do it since release 0.9.8.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlstate}[name=State]{A State}
\umlstatetext{Some

State

Content

$$x = y$$
}
\end{umlstate}
\end{tikzpicture}
```